# Node JS - Calling a method from another method in same file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this nodeJS code.

```
module.exports = {

  foo: function(req, res){
    ...
    this.bar(); // failing
    bar(); // failing
    ...
  },

  bar: function(){
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

I need to call the `bar()` method from inside the `foo()` method. I tried  `this.bar()` as well as `bar()`, but both fail saying `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'bar()'`.

How can I call one method from the other?

Comment: `module.exports.foo.call(this);` ?

Comment: @Danil foo is a request handler which is called from the router.

Comment: Something is definitely changing the `this` context but the question is who?

Comment: OK, tried `module.exports.foo()` and it works.. But will figure out why the context is missing..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
module.exports = {

  foo: function(req, res){

    bar();

  },
  bar: bar
}

function bar() {
  ...
}
```

No closure is needed.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted response is wrong, you need to call the bar method from the current scope using the "this" keyword:

```
    module.exports = {
      foo: function(req, res){

        this.bar();

      },
      bar: function() { console.log('bar'); }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think what you can do is [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the context before passing the callback.

```
something.registerCallback(module.exports.foo.bind(module.exports));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
module.exports = (function () {
    function realBar() {
        console.log('works');
    }
    return {

        foo: function(){
            realBar();
        },

        bar: realBar
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Is bar intended to be internal (private) to foo?

```
module.exports = {
    foo: function(req, res){
        ...
        function bar() {
            ...
            ...
        }
        bar();     
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. You can refer each function from anywhere (needs to import .js file)

```
function foo(req,res){
    console.log("you are now in foo");
    bar();
}
exports.foo = foo;

function bar(){
    console.log("you are now in bar");
}
exports.bar = bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

in Node js + Express, you can use this syntax in the same controller

```
//myController.js
exports.funA = () =>{

    console.log("Hello from funA!")

    //cal funB
    funB()

}

let funB = () =>{

    console.log("Hello from funB!")
}
```

make sure to use the **let** keyword before the function and call it with the **()** parentheses inside the main function

OUTPUT

```
App listening at http://localhost:3000
Hello from fun A!
Hello from fun B!
```