# How to call one method from another method

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call a “local” function within module.exports from another function in module.exports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462223/call-a-local-function-within-module-exports-from-another-function-in-module-ex)

I am using node.js for develop my application. I have to call one method within another method from my main.js. how do i do this?

i am explaining detail here.

### app.js

```
app.post('/getNotificationCount', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.setHeader('Expires', new Date().addYears(-10));
    try {
          //here i have my custom code/logic
          //i have to call '/getNotification' method here, i have to pass parameter too..
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('\r\n ' + new Date().toString() + ' - Try Catch from /getNotificationCount : ' + err + ' \r\n ');
        res.json({ error: 'Forbidden' }, 403);
    }
});

app.post('/getNotification', function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store');
    res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    res.contentType('application/json');
    res.setHeader('Expires', new Date().addYears(-10));
    try {
          //my sql code goes here !!!
          //I want retrieve parameter in req.body here...
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('\r\n ' + new Date().toString() + ' - Try Catch from /getNotification : ' + err + ' \r\n ');
        res.json({ error: 'Forbidden' }, 403);
    }
});
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can assign the function (method) to a variable and use that, also you can export your functions in other .js scripts.

**export.js**

```
exports.moduleFunction = function(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

**main.js**

```
// Import your module
var myModule = require('./export');

var myFunction = function(param) {
    console.log(param);
};

var main = function mainFunction() {
    // Call function in this same script
    myFunction('hello world!');
    // Call from module
    myModule.moduleFunction('Hello world from module export');
};

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

use module.exports concept..

to get an idea i am giving two links posted here..
[Node JS - Calling a method from another method in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274381/node-js-calling-a-method-from-another-method-in-same-file)

[Call a "local" function within module.exports from another function in module.exports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462223/call-a-local-function-within-module-exports-from-another-function-in-module-ex)

hope you will get an idea..